# Remover click com JQuery após clicar em outro elemento

Tags: jquery

Sempre que eu clico na **label** que está dentro de **bandeiras** ele deve aplicar um **background-color**. Está funcionando.
O que acontece, é que quando eu clico em uma div, ele aplica o background corretamente, mas quando eu clicar em outra, eu quero que ele remova o background-color da div anterior e deixe aplicada apenas na atual.

```js
$('.bandeiras label').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#8a8383');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bandeiras cf">
  <label for="codigoBandeiraV" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraV" name="codigoBandeira" value="visa">
  <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/visa.png" alt="Visa" title="Visa" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraM" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraM" name="codigoBandeira" value="master"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard" title="MasterCard" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraDin" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraDin" name="codigoBandeira" value="diners"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/dinners.png" alt="Diners" title="Diners" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraE" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraE" name="codigoBandeira" value="elo""><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/elo.png" alt="Elo" title="Elo" align="absmiddle"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar o `background-color` de todos os elementos de uma vez com o valor padrão antes de aplicar a nova cor ao elemento clicado:

```js
$('.bandeiras label').click(function() {
   $('.bandeiras label').css("background-color", "rgb(138, 131, 131)");
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bandeiras cf">
  <label for="codigoBandeiraV" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraV" name="codigoBandeira" value="visa">
  <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/visa.png" alt="Visa" title="Visa" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraM" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraM" name="codigoBandeira" value="master"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard" title="MasterCard" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraDin" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraDin" name="codigoBandeira" value="diners"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/dinners.png" alt="Diners" title="Diners" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraE" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraE" name="codigoBandeira" value="elo"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/elo.png" alt="Elo" title="Elo" align="absmiddle"></label>
</div>
```

### Pegando a cor original de forma automática

```js
var cor_padrao;
$('.bandeiras label').click(function(){
   cor_padrao = cor_padrao || $(this).css("background-color");
   $('.bandeiras label').css("background-color", cor_padrao);
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bandeiras cf">
  <label for="codigoBandeiraV" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraV" name="codigoBandeira" value="visa">
  <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/visa.png" alt="Visa" title="Visa" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraM" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
  <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraM" name="codigoBandeira" value="master"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard" title="MasterCard" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraDin" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraDin" name="codigoBandeira" value="diners"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/dinners.png" alt="Diners" title="Diners" align="absmiddle"></label>
  <label for="codigoBandeiraE" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);"><input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraE" name="codigoBandeira" value="elo"><img src="/assets/images/cartoes/elo.png" alt="Elo" title="Elo" align="absmiddle"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode usar os siblings do jQuery para isso. Quando vc adiciona um css em um vc retira o css dos irmãos.

```js
$('.bandeiras label').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#f00').siblings().css('background-color', '#8a8383');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js "></script>

<div class="bandeiras cf">
    <label for="codigoBandeiraV" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
        <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraV" name="codigoBandeira" value="visa">
        <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/visa.png" alt="Visa" title="Visa" align="absmiddle">
    </label>
    <label for="codigoBandeiraM" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
        <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraM" name="codigoBandeira" value="master">
        <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard" title="MasterCard" align="absmiddle">
    </label>
    <label for="codigoBandeiraDin" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
        <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraDin" name="codigoBandeira" value="diners">
        <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/dinners.png" alt="Diners" title="Diners" align="absmiddle">
    </label>
    <label for="codigoBandeiraE" class="cc-radio" style="background-color: rgb(138, 131, 131);">
        <input type="radio" id="codigoBandeiraE" name="codigoBandeira" value="elo">
        <img src="/assets/images/cartoes/elo.png" alt="Elo " title="Elo" align="absmiddle">
    </label>
</div>
```