# SlideToggle - configuração em Aberto e Fechado - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu irei apresentar a ideia que quero fazer em meu site e em seguida mostrarei o que já fiz e o que está funcionando corretamente e logo depois apresentarei o problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. Caso eu não seja claro em alguma parte, eu vou ficar super feliz de esclarecer para que a compreensão fique melhor.

**IDEIA:**
Eu estou fazendo uma tela de com informações sobre tipos de consultoria, para isso fiz 6 cards (Retangulo com Icone + nome) com os títulos que precisava. 
O que vai conter nessa interação de cards:

*Hover:*
- Alteração de cor no icone e titúlo do card;

*Event Click*:
- Faz requisição Ajax e exibe a  com resposta;
- Alteração de cor no icone e título do card;

**JÁ DESENVOLVIDO:**
Eu já consegui fazer a parte do hover, claro e o *Event Click* com Javascript, como segue abaixo:

Esse é o **HTML**:

```
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5" ">
                    <a data-consult-id="1">
                        <div class="text-center element">
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                                <i class="ti-package ti-icone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>
                                RH
                            </h4>
                        </div> <!-- feature -->
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5">
                    <a data-consult-id="2">
                        <div class="text-center element">
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                                <i class="ti-headphone-alt ti-icone"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4>
                                Processos Industriais
                            </h4>
                        </div> <!-- feature -->
                    </a>
                </div>
```

O **CSS** é:

```
.element {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 50px -6px rgba(84,84,120,.26);
        padding: 40px 20px 20px;
        position: relative;
        background: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .element h4 {
        color: #3c9890;
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .element:hover div i{
        background: rebeccapurple !important;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .element:hover h4{
        color: #9e6bd2 !important;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .ti-icone {
        background: #35b1a6;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 28px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

E aqui está o **Javascript**:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-consult-id]', function () {
        let consult_id = $(this).attr("data-consult-id");
        var obj = $(this);
        let response = $(".response-content");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "response.php?consult_id=" + consult_id,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(response).slideToggle('fast', function () {
                        $('a[data-consult-id] .element div').children('i').css("background-color", "");
                        $('.element div', obj).children('i').toggleClass('actived');
                        $('.element', obj).children('h4').toggleClass('text-actived');
                    }).html(data);
                }
            });
        }, 200);
    });
```

OBS.: Desculpa o detalhamento que pode parecer chato, mas se eu fizer simples demais ignoram a pergunta e podem dar negative, sla rsrs.

**PROBLEMA:**
Agora o meu problema é segundo o exemplo seguinte: Se eu clicar no card RH, a requisição será feita e retornará os dados para o **response**, ok e com isso eu adicionei um **SlideToggle** para efeito de *abrir* e *fechar* e também junto com isso eu coloquei uma função para que quando isso acontecer, ele adicione na tag **< i >** e na tag **< h4 >** a classe *.actived/.text-actived*, o que elas fazem pode ser visto logo abaixo:

```
.actived {
   background-color: #663399 !important;
}
.text-actived {
   color: #9e6bd2 !important;
}
```

Então, tendo esse card ativo, eu tenho ele exatamente como quero, porém se tendo esse card aberto eu clicar em outro card, por exemplo **Processos Industriais**, o **SlideToggle()** é desativado mas mesmo assim as classes *.actived/.text-actived* são adicionadas na tag **< i >** e na tag **< h4 >**.

Meu pedido é que alguem me ajude a entender como posso fazer essa funcionalidade para que quando eu clicar em um outro card, o antigo seja desativado e o AJAX do novo card seja aberto e exibido e com isso, a cor das tags "i" e "h4" do antigo tambem sejam desativadas e sejam ativadas no novo.

Bom, era isso. Como fiz na minha pergunta anterior, eu vou colocar o link do site que estou desenvolvendo essa funcionalidade para talvez vocês verem melhor.

http://hecato.com/sistema/info/consultores.php

Qualquer duvida, por favor, comentem e irei responder o mais rapido possivel. Eu também estou testando algumas formas para arrumar isso.

Obrigado a todos e que a força esteja....

Comment: Cara vc tem que pegar os `siblings()` e dar um removeClass talver seja interessante vc colocar o ID no elemento mais de "fora", na div com classe "col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5" , aqui tem dois exemplos as vezes podem te ajuda ai... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302705/remover-click-com-jquery-ap%C3%B3s-clicar-em-outro-elemento/302713#302713

Comment: Então mano, eu adaptei de acordo com os exemplos lá mas mesmo assim não funciona. Você pode me dar um exemplo sobre essa ideia do removeClass? Porque ele está dentro de uma requisição Ajax dentro do `success`. Essa ação impacta diretamente na hora de fechar o `response`

Comment: Cara infelizmente não manjo quase nada de JS e jQuery, nessa não vou conseguir te ajudar muito, achei que algum dos exemplos podia te ajudar. De qq forma logo logo aparece alguém pra te dar uma força!

Comment: @hugocsl ok vlw

Answer (score 0):

Basta você fazer remover a classe de todos os elementos e depois adicionar apenas no elemento clicado.

No seu `success`, ficaria assim:

```
success: function (data) {
                    $(response).slideToggle('fast', function () {
                        $('a[data-consult-id] .element div').children('i').css("background-color", "");
                        $('a[data-consult-id] .element div').children('i').removeClass("actived");
                        $('a[data-consult-id] .element').children('h4').removeClass("text-actived");

                        $('.element div', obj).children('i').toggleClass('actived');
                        $('.element', obj).children('h4').toggleClass('text-actived');
                    }).html(data);
                }
```

Resultado na sua página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se de adicionar o atributo  `[data-consult-id]` nos links, pois notei que tem um link sem ele.

Comment: Ah sim, pois então, no contexto do projeto, algumas não terão informações adicionadas, só 4. As outras estão ali para posteriormente. Mas ainda ele fecha quando é clicado em outro card. Eu vi um exemplo interessante num site e estive analisando o código deles pra ver se encontro como fizeram mas até agora nada '-'... Se puder me dar uma luz sobre isso tbm. Olha só [Exemplo Wickbold](https://www.wickbold.com.br/linhas-produtos/grao-sabor) Clica em um e ele abre e clica em outro ele passa para outro ainda aberto.